# VPS in OVH doesn't boot (stuck on SYSLINUX)

Tags: linux, debian, boot, ovh

I have a VPS in OVH. I think maybe they have updated the kernel and now my server is not going up.

I have entered in KVM and I see the system stuck with the message:

```
Booting from Hard Disk...
MBR

SYSLINUX 6.03 EDD 20150107 Copyright (C) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al
_ (cursor here)
```

I have accessed the server in rescue mode to see the boot. The file is on /boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf with the content:

```
default linux
timeout 1
label linux
kernel boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64
append initrd=boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/vda1 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 ro quiet
```

I have checked the file on the rescue system and it is the same.

I have opened a ticket but I need my system up fast.

Some ideas about fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with OVH.

My server expired so I paid after the expiration. Usually the system is going up again without problems but in this case **they assigned the wrong disk to the boot**.

The only solution possible was contact them and they fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, also on OVH after the last update.
After looking in the boot folder, I had two different versions:
vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 & vmlinuz-3.16.0-5-amd64
I changed in both extlinux.conf files the version and it worked.